# Nested class of a template class, static member variable of the template class

Tags: c++, templates, static, nested

The following code works:

```
template<typename T> class OtherClass
{
public:
    T member;
};

template<typename T> class MyClass
{         
public:
    vector<vector<OtherClass<T> > * > stacks;
};

template<typename T>
static vector<vector<OtherClass<T> > * > MyClass<T>::stacks =
    vector<vector<OtherClass<T> > * >(1024);
```

But this one does not:

```
template<typename T> class MyClass
{         
public:
    class OtherClass
    {
    public:
        T member;
    };

    static vector<vector<OtherClass> * > stacks;
};

template<typename T>
vector<vector<MyClass<T>::OtherClass> * > MyClass<T>::stacks =
    vector<vector<MyClass<T>::OtherClass> * >(1024);
```

gcc complains amongst other things:
error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template class vector'

Any idea how to nest the class?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

you need to tell the compiler that OtherClass is a nested type with typename

```
template<typename T>
vector<vector<typename MyClass<T>::OtherClass> * > MyClass<T>::stacks =
    vector<vector<MyClass<T>::OtherClass> * >(1024);
```

And no need to repeat the type twice :

```
template<typename T>
vector<vector<typename MyClass<T>::OtherClass> * > MyClass<T>::stacks (1024);
```

If you do not wants to repeat a complex original type, use typedef, still needing typename :

```
// in Myclass : using StackType = vector<vector<OtherClass>*>;
template<typename T>
typename MyClass<T>::StackType MyClass<T>::stacks (1024);
```